# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Why is Cordova code not working when placed in a sub-page?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I tried out the [Cordova camera example](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html) inside my Worklight application.
It works only when the camera code is inside the main HTML file (index.html).

When I place it in another HTML file, it does not work.
Why is that? What am I missing?

Comment: Explain how you have navigated to another page and only then we can help.

Comment: Hi Idan. I opened another html file using an <a href> tag. How do you preserve the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worklight is a Single Page Application. Thus you cannot simply load another HTML file and expect your application to continue functioning; this includes Cordova.

Read the ["Building a multi-page application" training module](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#client-basics) and review the accompanying sample project, to better understand how to create a multi-page application.

You can also review these sample applications (after reading the training module):

- [JQM_multipage_load_changePage.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a4kocwo205s049b/JQM_multipage_load_changePage.zip) - uses either `.load` or `.changePage`
- [JQM_multipage_changePage_pageshow.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8f0xr9ogp4ofuqs/JQM_multipage_changePage_pageshow.zip) - uses `.changePage` and `.pageShow`

Comment: Thanks Idan. I'll go through the samples and the training module. I'll get back to you when I'm done.